# What happens if timeout handler is not cancelled inside lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that sets timeout handler with a certain delay (60 seconds) at the beginning.
I 'd like to know what is the exact behavior of lambda when the timeout handler is not cancelled till the lambda returns response (in less than 60 seconds). Especially, when there are hundreds of lambda invocation, the uncancelled timeout handler in the previous lambda execution will affect the next process that runs on the same instance?  More info - lambda function is invoked asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't mentioned which language you're using or provided any code indicating how you're creating timeouts, but the general process is described at [AWS Lambda execution environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html).

Lambda freezes the execution environment following an invocation and it remains frozen, up to a certain maximum amount of time (15 mins afaik), and is thawed if a new invocation happens quickly enough, and the prior execution environment is re-used.

A key quote from the documentation is:

> Background processes or callbacks that were initiated by your Lambda function and did not complete when the function ended [will] resume if Lambda reuses the execution environment. Make sure that any background processes or callbacks in your code are complete before the code exits.

Comment: I don't think the language is not a problem here but your answer makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. That doc page is a good read. The point I was hoping to make was that without actual code, we don't know for sure what this timeout handler is, so we don't know for sure what its behavior would be. If this were C++ and the object representing the timeout handler went out of scope then its destructor might cancel the timeout. Obviously this is an unlikely scenario, and almost certainly not relevant to your case, but it's always going to be better to know what we're dealing with (JavaScript and setTimeout, for example). Anyhow, no  big deal.

Comment: Yeah, the lambda code is written in Python. Thanks again for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote in the comments, the lambda is written in python.
This simple example shows that the event is passing to the next invocation:

The code:

```
import json
import signal 
import random

def delayed(val):
    print("Delayed:", val)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    r = random.random()
    print("Generated", r)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, lambda *args: delayed(r))
    signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 1)
    return {'statusCode': 200}
```

Yields:
[Cloudwatch logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OYE8.png)

Think about the way that AWS implements lambdas:
When a lambda is being invoked, a container is being raised and the environment starts to initialize (this is the `cold-start` phase).
During this initialization, the python interpreter is starting, and behind the scene, an AWS code fetches events from the lambda service and triggers your handler.
This initialization is costly, so AWS prefers to wait with the same "process" for the next event. On the happy flow, it arrives "fast enough" after the previous finished, so they spared the initialization and everyone is happy.
Otherwise, after a small period, they will shutdown the container.
As long as the interpreter is still on - the signal that we fired in one invocation will leak to the next invocation.

Note also the concurrency of the lambdas - two invocations that run in parallel are running on different containers, thus have different interpreters and this alarm will not leak.